# Querying a database table without an entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

Is it possible, using Entity Manager or some other JPA API to execute a query and get results, in say like as a List, without having to create an Entity class for the same.

Basically, I want to be able to **only** read data from table with table name being passed dynamically during run time.

Comment: If you're not using a mapped class, why not just use JDBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `createNativeQuery` like this:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname FROM Author a WHERE a.id = :id");
q.setParameter("id", id);
Object[] author = (Object[]) q.getSingleResult();

System.out.println("Author "
        + author[0]
        + " "
+ author[1]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use PreparedStatements?

Comment: @SamzSakerz I converted it to what you said tnx :)